# Finding the position of the lowest all-white line

Tags: imagemagick

How to find the position of the lowest all-white line in the upper half of the image (marked in red) ?
How to find the position of the highest all-white line in the lower half of the image (marked in blue) ?

Alternatively, how to find a bounding box of the "grid area" ?
I would like to use the coordinates of this bounding box to define a `-region` for subsequent operations (e.g. for color replacements), so I would appreciate a hint how to set this region to the position and size of this bounding box.

[image: Annotated Input Image]

Raw input image:
[image: Raw input image]

The background color is dependably white `rgb(255,255,255)`.
The image size is constant.
The vertical position and height of the "grid area" is variable.
The "grid area" always contains non-white pixels.

EDIT:
This code outputs the coordinates of these red & blue lines in its textual output:

```
magick input.png -alpha off \
-threshold 99.6%% \
-statistic minimum "%%[fx:int(w/255)]x1"  \
-scale 1x! \
-threshold 99.6%% \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:exclude-header=true \
-connected-components 4 result.png
```

However, I have no idea how to cause `-connected-components` to list only the first object with the largest area (which contains the sought coordinates) or how to use this object as a`region` in subsequent ImageMagick operations.

Comment: Post the original image without your red and blue lines. Show your code. What have you tried?  See -connected-components in ImageMagick at https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php

Comment: No, my red an blue lines significantly aid in the visualization of my question and they do not affect the all-white line finding algorithm, because I deliberately left a row of white pixels between these lines and the grid area. Also, I doubt that you will reverse your downvote even if I remove these annotation  lines.

Comment: If you want help, you need to provide the input image, so others can work with your image and provide code. Working on your image with the colored lines, distorts the image so that the result may not be the same. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am going to go out on a limb that you are not just nit-picking and post a second image without these lines.  P.S. I tried `connected-components` and it identified too many objects even after black&white thresholding.  I find its documentation incomplete and cryptic.

Comment: Thanks for posting your original image. See my answer below.

Comment: For example `-define connected-components:keep-top=1` doesn't just list the 1st object from the top. It changes the coordinates of the first object!  WTF?!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get the bounding box of the table in Unix syntax ImageMagick (on my Mac). If you want the white above and below the bounding box, then subtract one from the top and add one to the bottom coordinates.

- Read the image, turn alpha off, threshold and invert (negate) so the lines are white on black background
- Make a copy (clone) and apply horizontal morphology to fill in gaps in the horizontal lines
- Make another copy (clone) and apply vertical morphology to fill in gaps in the vertical lines without causing the text at the top to merge with the outer lines.
- Delete the original
- Combine the horizontal and vertical lines
- Apply connected components processing, filtering on area so that only the largest two areas remain as a white rectangle on the black background (with one black cutout that does not matter for getting the bounds of the white rectangle)
- Extract the bounding box (WxH+X+Y)
- From the bounding box, extract the top=Y and the bottom=(Y+H-1)

I have saved some temporary images to show you the steps.

```
bbox=`convert table.png -alpha off -threshold 10% -negate +write tmp0.png \
\( -clone 0 -virtual-pixel black -morphology close rectangle:25x1 +write tmp1.png \) \
\( -clone 0 -virtual-pixel black -morphology close rectangle:1x10 +write tmp2.png \) \
-delete 0 \
-compose plus -composite -type bilevel +write tmp3.png \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:exclude-header=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=20000 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 \
tmp4.png | grep "gray(255)" | awk '{print $2}'`
echo "$bbox"
bbox=`echo $bbox | tr "x" "+"`
top=`echo $bbox | cut -d+ -f3`
height=`echo $bbox | cut -d+ -f2`
bottom=$((top+height-1))
echo "top=$top bottom=$bottom"
```

Negated threshold (tmp0)

[image]

Horizontal gaps filled image (tmp1)

[image]

Vertical gaps (mostly) filled image (tmp2):

[image]

Combined horizontal and vertical images (tmp3) (All but one of the gaps around the bounding (outside) lines are filled (the inside ones do not matter):

[image]

Connected Components area filtered image:

[image]

Textual Information Output (first line is bbox=WxH+X+Y):

```
1258x762+11+141
top=11 bottom=772
```

Here is an alternate method.

```
convert table.png -alpha off -threshold 10% -negate +write tmp0.png \
\( -clone 0 -virtual-pixel black -morphology close rectangle:25x1 +write tmp1.png \) \
\( -clone 0 -virtual-pixel black -morphology close rectangle:1x10 +write tmp2.png \) \
-delete 0 \
-compose plus -composite -type bilevel +write tmp3.png \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:exclude-header=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=20000 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 tmp4.png

convert tmp4.png -format "%@\n" info: | head -n 1
echo "$bbox"
bbox=`echo $bbox | tr "x" "+"`
top=`echo $bbox | cut -d+ -f3`
height=`echo $bbox | cut -d+ -f2`
bottom=$((top+height-1))
echo "top=$top bottom=$bottom"
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a very complex procedure and code.  I could not verify its functionality because I do not have the `awk` and `head` and `tr` and `cut` commands on my system.  Is there a way to set a `-region` for subsequent ImageMagick operations based on the discovered bounding box, WITHOUT extracting it as text ?

Comment: What is your IM version and platform?  My second set of commands above can be used more manually or if you are on Windows, then there are equivalent operations or you can load Unix tools on your Windows system. But the command `convert tmp4.png -format "%@\n" info:` will list two lines of data. The first line should be `21: 1258x762+11+141 633.0,520.9 945428 gray(255)`, which is the white object as its color is gray(255). The bounding box `1258x762+11+141` can be used as the argument to -region if on IM 6 and not IM 7.

Comment: v 7.0.10-24 Q8 x64 2020-07-18

Comment: With Q8, -connected-components can only process 256 regions, whereas in Q16 it can do 65535 regions. In IM 7, for my commands replace convert with magick.

Comment: Why do I have to use the external `head` command to process the ImageMagic's output?  Can't I just use the coordinates of the object found by `connected-components` to directly define a `region` for subsequent I.M. operations?  Also, why `-define connected-components:keep-top=1` doesn't just list the 1st object from the top, but changes the coordinates of the first object, instead ?!

Comment: On my 7.0.10-24 Q16, it does not filter from 2 to 1 line when I add that to my second set of commands. I will report the bug. What is your platform?

Comment: I believe the issue is that you cannot get rid of the background date when you have only 2 objects when filtering out objects There has to be a background if there is a foreground object. Nevertheless, I will report it and see what they say.

Comment: My platform is Windows v7 x64 :(